# Not able to configure gem 'six' in Rails

Tags: ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 in my project with different roles in my app, have to give different access permission to different roles for that i am using `gem 'six'`. But couldn't able to configure it .

In my `user Model` have defined

```
ROLES = %w[ ADMIN STUDENT TEACHER ]
```

My application controller

```
 before_action :add_abilities
 helper_method :abilities, :can?

 def abilities
   @abilities ||= Six.new
 end

 private
 def can?(object, action, subject)
   abilities.allowed?(object, action, subject)
 end
 def add_abilities
   abilities << Ability
 end
```

my ability.rb

`

```
class Ability
  class << self
    def allowed(user, subject)
      return [] unless user.kind_of?(User)

      case subject.class.name
      when "School" then school_abilities(user, subject)
      when "Standard" then standard_abilities(user, subject)
      when "Section" then section_abilities(user, subject)
      when "Subject" then subject_abailities(user, subject)
      when "Test" then test_abilities(user, subject)
      when "Teach" then teach_abitities(user,subject)
      when "Study" then Study_abilities(user,subject)
      when "Participate" then participate_abilities(user, subject)
      else []
      end.concat(global_abilities(user))
    end

    def global_abilities(user)
      rules = []
      rules << :create_school
      rules
    end

    def school_abilities(user, school)
      rules = []

      # if User::ROLES.first == "ADMIN"
      #   rules += school_admin_rules
      # end
      # if User::ROLES.last == "TEACHER"
      #   rule += school_teacher_rules
      # end
      # if User::ROLES.second == "STUDENT"
      #   rule += school_student_rules
      # end
      if user.role == "ADMIN"
        rules += school_admin_rules
      end
      if user.role == "TEACHER"
        rule += school_teacher_rules
      end
      if user.role == "STUDENT"
        rule += school_student_rules
      end

      rules.flatten
    end

    def school_student_rules
      [
        :read_test
      ]
   end

    def school_teacher_rules
      [
        :read_test,
        :write_test,
        :modify_test,
        :create_test
      ]
    end

    def school_admin_rules
      [
        :admin_school,
        :change_school,
        :rename_school,
        :remove_school,
        :modify_school,
        :write_school
      ]

    end

    [:issue, :note, :snippet, :merge_request].each do |name|
      define_method "#{name}_abilities" do |user, subject|
        if subject.school == user
          [
            :"read_#{name}",
            :"write_#{name}",
            :"modify_#{name}",
            :"admin_#{name}"
          ]
        elsif subject.respond_to?(:teach) && subject.teach == user
          [
            :"read_#{name}",
            :"write_#{name}",
            :"modify_#{name}"
          ]
        elsif subject.respond_to?(:study) && subject.study == user
          [
            :"read_#{name}",
            :"write_#{name}"
          ]
        else
          subject.respond_to?(:school) ? school_abilities(user, subject.school) : []
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

`

If select role is teacher she only can access test controller not any other controller. How can i do. Someone please help me out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is the link to to gitlab project in this project its very well define how to use the permission using `gem six` hopefully it will help you enjoy](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/models/ability.rb)